# Remove border on specific td element of html table

Tags: html, css

I use this code to remove border on specific td element.

```html
<table border>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style='border-right:none;border-left:none;border-bottom:none;border-top:none'>no border</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

What is wrong? Please someone give an example of two td elements. The first i want to have a border and the second i do not want to have a border. How can i achieve this?

Comment: I'm not really sure what the question is - is the code not working? To start off with, you can combine all the `border-*` properties into one, `border: none;`

Comment: I put your code in a snippet and it seems fine

Comment: Not working in my code and its driving me crazy.

Comment: Please someone give an example of two td elements. One i want to have a border and the other i do not want to have a border. How can i achieve this?

Comment: @j08691 

I've added `<table border>` and `border:none` has no effect as it should.

Comment: So how can i achieve one td element with border and the next one without border?

Comment: @c-smile - What you see is the table's border, not the cell's border.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tables have peculiar rendering model.

As an option is to use border-color:transparent:

```html
<table border>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style='border-color:transparent'>no border</td>
      <td>normal cell</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate it!

Comment: "You can discard border either on all cells or none. ". That's incorrect. `border:none` works just as well as `border-color:transparent` there.

Answer (score 0):

Just trying to put css > `border:none;`